# How can i get the label value by using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, label

i am beginner of jquery.How can i get the label value through jquery?
Below is my coding

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = "asdasd";
    }
}
```

Html

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text;
            alert (g);


        });

    });


 </script>
```

The alert function is not working :(

Comment: Wondering -ve voting. The person says that he is a beginner. A little note behind -ve voting could help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your script as follows and try

```
<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text();
         alert (g);           
    });      

 //Comment out the last parenthesis
 //});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a function, not a property. Put a pair of parentheses after it:

```
    var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close

```
var g = $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text();
```

More information on [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `});`. Also you shouldn't have a space between `alert` and the left parentheses. Also `text` is a function so you should also add the `()` at the end of the statement.